# Java Spring multiple url mapping values

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I've been trying to implement a generic interface to support multiple access controls.
Currently, I have the following controller:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api")
public interface MyController {

  @GetMapping(value = {"/public/workers/name/{workerString}"})
  ResponseEntity<T> searchByName(@PathVariable String workerString);

  @GetMapping("/hr/worker/general/{id}")
  ResponseEntity<T> general(@PathVariable int id);

}
```

I have an interceptor which catches the request and checks wheather the user has the "hr" permissions.
Now I have the need to add another scenario, where the user can have "hd" permission and he can execute the same procedure.
The easy solution is to do the following:

```
@GetMapping(value={"/hr/worker/general/{id}","/hd/worker/general/{id}"})
 ResponseEntity<T> general(@PathVariable int id);
```

and my `interceptor` will check in a generic manner whether the user has the permission depends on the url.

My issue with this is scalability. what if tomorrow I have to add another type of permission? "hm" "hs" and so on.. **I don't want to add more urls to the mapping**.
Is that possible to do something like that? :

```
 @GetMapping("/{permission}/worker/general/{id}")
 ResponseEntity<T> general(@PathVariable int id);
```

Obviously this doesn't work since I have to consume the declared path variable.
what are the alternatives here and what would be considered a good practice?

I would appreciate any thought or help here. Thanks.

Comment: Why not consuming the permission path variable?

Comment: I don't think it will be a good idea since I wont be using the declared variable. its possible of course, but not sure if considered a good practice.

Comment: Maybe you need/will need it, but it seems as a valid parameter

Comment: A good practice, of course, would be to avoid declaring multiple URIs pointing to the same resource, and instead use `@Secured/@RollesAllowed`